# How to use socket.io-redis with multiple servers?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, socket.io-redis

i have following code on two machines

```
 var server       = require('http').createServer(app);
    io               = require('socket.io')(server);
    var redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
    io.adapter(redisAdaptebr({host: config.redis.host, port: config.redis.port}));
    server.listen(config.port, function () {
```

and I store socket.id of every client connected to these two machines on central db, ID of sockets is being saved and event sending on same server works flawlessly, but when I try to send message to the socket of other server it doesn't work..

```
subSocket = io.sockets.connected[userSocketID];
   subSocket.emit('hello',{a:'b'})
```

1. How can i know that redis is wokring good.
2. How to send message to socket connected on another server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Socket.IO requires sticky sessions.  The socket must communicate solely with the originating process.

[docs](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/)

You can have the socket.io servers communicate to each other to pass events around, but the client must continue talking to the process with which it originated.

Comment: So how can i send event from server, to another server's socket?

Comment: There are recommendations on how to do that at the bottom of the documentation to which I linked.

Comment: as mentioned above i tried the same doc, redis adapter. but no use :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar issue but I can answer your first question.
you can monitor all the commands processed by redis using that command on the terminal:

```
redis-cli monitor
```

http://redis.io/commands/MONITOR

Unfortunately I cannot help you further as I am still having issues even though both server are sending something to redis.